# Движение шарика арканоид

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Пишу арканоид, как учебную программу. Столкнулся с такой проблемой, как сделать движение шарика? Как можно прописать вектор движения? Я пытался через `Offset`, но он не учитывает угол ударения.
Не обязательно, но было бы лучше, если бы вектор движения был адаптирован под отдельный класс, например `Moving`.
По заданию нельзя использовать движки типа `Unity` или иных, необходимо использовать лишь стандартные средства.

Мой вариант через `Offset`

```
if (ball.Left == 400)
{
    ball.Offset(-1, -1);
    pictureBox1.Invalidate();
}
else if (ball.Top == 400)
{
    ball.Offset(1, 1);
    pictureBox1.Invalidate();
}
```

Я не понимаю как сделать, чтобы мячик учитывал угол. Он может прилететь в одну точку справа, а может слева, от этого зависит его дальнейшее направление, как это можно прописать?

Comment: уточнения нужно вносить в вопрос, внизу есть кнопка [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/657197/edit).

Comment: как вектор может не учитывать угол, когда он сам задает  собственный угол? Покажите как вы пытались сделать через Offset.

Comment: В момент удара просто высчитывайте новую скорость по `x` и `y`. Вообще неясно, что делает у вас `Offset(int,int)`

Comment: @AGS
 а можете приблизительно показать, пожалуйста? хотя бы схематически

Comment: Что-то вроде https://www.screencast.com/t/Eys6qIsqf

Comment: спасибо, попробую записать в программу

Comment: @AGS17 оформили бы более развернуто в виде ответа.

Answer (score 2):

[image: траектория движения шара после удара о стену]

Основываясь на этой картинке мы можем высчитать общую формулу расчета угла после удара `2*y-x`, где `y` - угол наклона стены, `x` - угол движения шара до удара (относительно оси X).

Ниже представил класс `Mover`, который, собственно, и будет отвечать за передвижение шара. Классы `Position` и `Vector` отвечают за положение и вектор движения шара соответсвенно.

```
public class Mover
{
    private readonly Timer _timer;


    public Vector Vector { get; }

    public Position Position { get; }

    public TimeSpan UpdateInterval
    {
        get => TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(_timer.Interval);
        set => _timer.Interval = value.Milliseconds;
    }


    public event EventHandler<MovedEventArgs> Moved;


    public Mover(TimeSpan updateInterval)
    {
        _timer = new Timer();
        _timer.Elapsed += TimerOnTick;

        Vector = new Vector();
        Position = new Position();
        UpdateInterval = updateInterval;
    }


    public void Start()
    {
        _timer.Start();
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        _timer.Stop();
    }


    private void TimerOnTick(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        Position.X += Vector.SpeedX;
        Position.Y += Vector.SpeedY;
        Moved?.Invoke(this, new MovedEventArgs(Position));
    }
}



public class MovedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public Position NewPosition { get; }


    public MovedEventArgs(Position newPosition)
    {
        NewPosition = newPosition;
    }
}



public class Position : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private double _x;
    private double _y;
    private double _width;
    private double _height;


    public double X
    {
        get => _x;
        set
        {
            if (SetProperty(ref _x, value))
            {
                NotifyProperty(nameof(Left));
                NotifyProperty(nameof(Right));
            }
        }
    }

    public double Y
    {
        get => _y;
        set
        {
            if (SetProperty(ref _y, value))
            {
                NotifyProperty(nameof(Top));
                NotifyProperty(nameof(Bottom));
            }
        }
    }

    public double Width
    {
        get => _width;
        set
        {
            if (SetProperty(ref _width, value))
            {
                NotifyProperty(nameof(Left));
                NotifyProperty(nameof(Right));
            }
        }
    }

    public double Height
    {
        get => _height;
        set
        {
            if (SetProperty(ref _height, value))
            {
                NotifyProperty(nameof(Top));
                NotifyProperty(nameof(Bottom));
            }
        }
    }

    public double Left => X - Width / 2;

    public double Right => X + Width / 2;

    public double Top => Y + Height / 2;

    public double Bottom => Y - Height / 2;


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;


    private void NotifyProperty([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private bool SetProperty<T>(ref T target, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (target.Equals(value))
        {
            return false;
        }
        target = value;
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

        return true;
    }
}



public class Vector
{
    private double _angleRadians;
    private double _speed;

    public double Speed
    {
        get => _speed;
        set
        {
            _speed = value;
            UpdateXYSpeed();
        }
    }

    public double AngleDegrees
    {
        get => _angleRadians * 180 / Math.PI;
        set
        {
            _angleRadians = value / 180 * Math.PI;
            UpdateXYSpeed();
        }
    }

    public double SpeedX { get; private set; }

    public double SpeedY { get; private set; }


    public void KickWall()
    {
        Kick(90);
    }

    public void KickFloor()
    {
        Kick(0);
    }

    public void Kick(double wallAngleDegrees)
    {
        AngleDegrees = 2 * wallAngleDegrees - AngleDegrees;
    }


    private void UpdateXYSpeed()
    {
        SpeedX = Math.Cos(_angleRadians) * _speed;
        SpeedY = Math.Sin(_angleRadians) * _speed;
    }
}
```

Вам требуется задать начальные значения положения шара, его скорости и угла полета. Так же подписываясь на событие `Moved` вы можете просчитывать текущее положение и, при столкновении, изменять вектор на соответсвующий угол. Методы `KickWall()` и `KickFloor()` используйте для отражения угла по X и Y осей соответсвенно. Метод `Kick(double)` - для удара о произвольную стену, передавая угол наклона этой стены.

Я написал класс `Position` для использования биндингов в WPF, вам нужно будет его упростить для WinForms.